# Justification for taking derivatives through maps between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Consider two manifolds M and N and a smooth map $F:M\rightarrow N$. Let's put that map aside for a minute and consider something else first.

Scenario 1:

We know that if $\exists$ $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we can pick an atlas, and consider curves in $M$ and tangent vectors to those curves and then take directional derivatives of $f$ at any given point $p\in M$ etc.

Scenario 2:

If we had another map $g: N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and we wanted to take derivatives of $g$ at points in $N$, we could just do a similar thing like for $M$ and $f$ in Scenario 1.

Scenario 3:

Now let's get back to $F:M\rightarrow N$. We know that we can let $dF_p:T_pM\rightarrow T_{F(p)}N$ be the map between tangent spaces and that will be represented by the Jacobian matrix etc and we can use this structure to compute derivatives of  $g:N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

My question is this: If we want to take derivatives of $g:N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, why are we going through the trouble of Scenario 3 when we can have Scenario 2?

Comment: You don't need $F$ to compute the derivative of $g$.

Comment: But yet it's advertised so much in all these textbooks..

Comment: It will be clearer if you can point out some reference.

Comment: Jack Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds page 55 to 60 or even Loring Tu's Introduction to Manifolds page 87 to 88.

Comment: I don't have the book written by Tu, but in Lee's book (at p.55-60) they are just defining the differential of $F$. I don't see scenario 3 there.

Comment: Look at figure 3.3 on page 55 and then see the line lower down that says $dF_p(v)(f)=v(f\circ F)$. They are taking the derivative of $f$ through $dF$.

Comment: Note that in Lee, the tangent plane is defined as the space of derivation, and in order to define what is $dF_p$, they have to specify, for each $v\in T_pM$, what is $dF_p(v)$, and to do so they have to define what is $dF_p(v) (f)$. In Lee's book, $dF_p$ is not defined as the action of Jacobian matrix in local coordinates.

Comment: Yes I understand that. In retrospect, I need not mention the Jacobian and I know that it's not mentioned in Lee's text where I'm looking. But if I understand you correctly, you're saying that defining $dF_p(v)(f)$ is merely a necessary piece of information to give a complete definition of $dF_p$ (since we need to know what it would do to $f$. So, in this way per my scenarios, we know how to measure the change in $g$ from point to point in $M$ but we could independently have measured the change in $g$ from point to point in $N$ if we wanted that. Correct?